# How to make "own" C++ string class convert automatically to python strings in bindings

Tags: c++, python, boost, boost-python

C++ code

```
class MyOwnString; // assume this implements a string class.

class HasMyOwnString // simple example that uses it
{
 private:
MyOwnString m_name;
int m_age;

  public:
HasMyOwnString( MyOwnString const& name, int age ) :
  m_name( name ), m_age( age )
{
}

MyOwnString name() const
{
    return m_name;
}

int age() const
{
    return m_age;
}
};

class HasStdString
{
   private:
std::string m_name;
int m_age;

   public:
HasStdString( std::string const& name, int age ) :
  m_name( name ), m_age( age )
{
}

std::string name() const
{
    return m_name;
}

int age() const
{
    return m_age;
}
};

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(test_cpp)
{
using namespace boost::python;
using boost::noncopyable;

class_<HasMyOwnString>( "HasMyOwnString", init<MyOwnString, int>() )
    .def( "name", &HasMyOwnString::name )
    .def( "age", &HasMyOwnString::age );

class_<HasStdString>( "HasStdString", init<std::string, int>() )
    .def( "name", &HasStdString::name )
    .def( "age", &HasStdString::age );
}
```

Assume all the relevant headers have been included. The above does build into a python .pyd.

Now here is the Python that I would like to work:

```
myStdStringTest = test_cpp.HasStdString( "UsesStdString", 1 )
name = myStdStringTest.name()
age = myStdStringTest.age()

print( name, age, type(name) )

myOwnStringTest = test_cpp.HasMyOwnString( "UsesOwnString", 2 )

name = myOwnStringTest.name()
age = myOwnStringTest.age()

print( name, age, type(name) )
```

The first part of the Python works, i.e. HasStdString. It knows how to automatically convert the Python str input to a std::string for the binding to work.

The second part fails expecting a MyOwnString.

1. MyOwnString has an implicit constructor from const char *
2. I have tried various things, hooking in some of boost's overloads, but can't find anything that works.

I have searched boost's code to see how they get str to convert to std::string automatically. The macro in operators.hpp makes no sense whatsoever. The macros in builtin_converters.hpp do make sense but they seem to do all the conversion the other way (aside from them having compiler errors in my 1.50.0 version) and didn't solve the problem.

Essentially the API I am trying to expose to Python has its own string class. Ok, bad enough that it does, I can't change that. But I would like this to be oblivious to Python users, and I would like the equivalent Python API to use Python strings wherever the "custom" string is used in the C++ code. I would like to define the conversion in one place, then for it to work everywhere I bind a function.

(For the sake of those who want a MyOwnString implementation to work with, I have made my own one here)

```
class MyOwnString
{
public:
    MyOwnString() 
      : m_internal()
    {
        init();
    }

    MyOwnString( const char * val ) 
        : m_internal()
    {
        init();
        assign( val, strlen( val ) );
    }

    MyOwnString( MyOwnString const& other )
        : m_internal()
    {
        init();
        assign( other.c_str(), other.m_len );
    }

    MyOwnString( const char * val, size_t len )
        : m_internal()
    {
        init();
        assign( val, len );
    }

    ~MyOwnString()
    {
        cleanup();
    }

    const char * c_str() const
    {
        return m_data;
    }

    size_t size() const
    {
        return m_len;
    }

    bool empty() const
    {
        return m_len == 0;
    }

    void clear()
    {
        cleanup();
        m_internal[0] = '\0';
    }

    MyOwnString & operator=( MyOwnString const& other )
    {
        assign( other.c_str(), other.m_len );
        return *this;
    }

    MyOwnString & operator=( const char * val )
    {
        assign( val, strlen(val) );
        return *this;
    }

private:

    void init()
    {
        m_data = m_internal;
        m_capacity = 0;
        m_len = 0;
    }

    void cleanup()
    {
        if( m_data != m_internal )
        {
            delete [] m_data;
            m_capacity = 0;
            m_data = m_internal;
        }
    }

    void assign( const char * text, size_t len ) // length not including null
    {
        if( len < EInternalSize ) // it fits into internal buffer
        {
            memcpy( m_internal, text, len );
            m_internal[len]='\0';
            cleanup(); // if we have dynamically allocated data remove it
            m_len = len;
        }
        else if( m_capacity > len ) // fits into already assigned buffer
        {
            memcpy( m_data, text, len );
            m_internal[len]='\0';
            m_len = len;
        }
        else
        {
            // We need to allocate. Do that before we delete any existing buffer

            char * buf = new char[ len + 1 ];
            memcpy( buf, text, len );
            buf[len] = '\0';

            cleanup(); // if there was a buffer there remove it
            m_data = buf;
            m_capacity = len + 1;
            m_len = len;
        }
    }


    enum { EInternalSize = 16 };
    size_t m_len;
    size_t m_capacity;
    char m_internal[EInternalSize];
    char * m_data;
};
```

To summarise the question it is:

What do I need to add to my bindings to allow the binding of HasMyOwnString to work as-is with the supplied Python also working...

(I don't mind changing the init part in HasMyOwnString, I would like any other functions that don't require me to supply the parameter type to work).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is answered in the [FAQ of Boost.Python](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/python/doc/v2/faq.html#custom_string).

You need to implement and register suitable `custom_string_to_python_str` and `custom_string_from_python_str` functions.

Comment: Thank you. This answered the question. I think it would have been better implemented in boost as a "template" so I would only need to write 2 small pieces of code to do it, however it works and I hopefully only need to do this once.